# xUnit testing with FilePicker

Tags: maui, xunit.net

I want to test following method for the correct setting of the ImageCountBelow10 boolean. I created a PickerService which calls the filepicker to get the images. In the test i am creating a Mock of this Pickerservice which then gets used in the cutImagesViewModel instance for testing. The problem now is that i still get the error

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePickerFileType' threw an exception.
---- Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException : This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
```

although from my understanting the Mock should not even use the FilePicker anymore and just return an empty IEnumerable. I could not find anything helpful on google as well so i am very confused why this is not working here.

Method to test:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async Task UploadMore() {
  IEnumerable < FileResult > result = await _pickerService.PickMultiplesAsync(new PickOptions {
    PickerTitle = "Choose Images",
      FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images
  });
  await Task.Delay(250);
  foreach(FileResult file in result) {
    Stream up = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    Guid id;
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
      up.CopyTo(stream);
      CropImageModel model = new CropImageModel(stream.ToArray());
      UploadImages.Add(model);
      croppedImages.Add(model);
      model.Index = croppedImages.Count;
    }
  }
  if (UploadImages.Count > 10) {
    await OpenPopup();
  }
}

[RelayCommand]
public async Task OpenPopup() {
  ImagesCountBelow10 = false;
  DeleteBool = true;
  TooManyImagesPopup pop = new TooManyImagesPopup() {
    BindingContext = this
  };
  await NavigationService.PushPopup(pop);
}
```

Testing Method:

```cs
private readonly CutImagesViewModel _cutImagesViewModel;
public CutImagesViewModelTests() {
  _cutImagesViewModel = new CutImagesViewModel(_navigationServiceMock.Object, _pickerService.Object) {
    UploadImages = new ObservableCollection < CropImageModel > ()
  };
}

[Fact]
public async void UploadMore_ImagesCount11ShouldOpenPupup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    _cutImagesViewModel.UploadImages.Add(new MauiDoggoApp.Models.CropImageModel(new byte[1] {
      (byte) i
    }));
  }

  await _cutImagesViewModel.UploadMoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);

  Assert.False(_cutImagesViewModel.ImagesCountBelow10);
}
```

and in the Base test class:

```cs
public class BaseViewModelTests {
  protected readonly Mock < INavigationService > _navigationServiceMock;
  protected readonly Mock < IPickerService > _pickerService;

  public BaseViewModelTests() {
    _navigationServiceMock = new Mock < INavigationService > ();
    _pickerService = new Mock < IPickerService > ();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? What's the `IPickerService `,`INavigationService`? If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?